# How to fix LazyInitializationException with @Transactional?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Does transaction borders demarcation impact session lifetime?

I have some simple spring boot app:

```
@Entity
public class Human {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<Hobby> hobbies = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters/setters
}


@Entity
public class Hobby {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    // getters/setters
}
```

And some service to test it:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootTransactionsApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private HumanRepo humanRepo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootTransactionsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        foo();
    }

    @javax.transaction.Transactional
    public void foo() {
        Human human = new Human();
        human.getHobbies().add(new Hobby());
        humanRepo.save(human);

        for (Human h : humanRepo.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(h.getHobbies());
        }
    }

}
```

So I expecting the framework to fetch the missed data (hobbies) as the method foo is marked as Transactional. But failed with `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection` Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Enable Transaction management using `@EnableTransactionManagement` and
Use `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` annotation instead of `@javax.transaction.Transactional`.